# APA Abstract is not justified correctly and title redundancy

Tags: apa6

Problem 1: The output pdf has an abstract indented to the left. How to make it justified?

Problem 2: How to remove/hide the title "Airbus" before Introduction in Page 3? The running title is already there, hence this title redundancy is unwanted.

Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,12pt,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Airbus}
\shorttitle{Airbus}
\author{Writer}
\affiliation{LSE}

\abstract{This paper provides an overview on the history of Airbus, its time evolution from early establishment to present day emphasizing on the information systems and technology. The objectives are to explore how Airbus as a manufacturing company embraced Information Systems and Technology to run its business and transformed into a data driven company. From its day-to-day operation to strategic plans, Airbus' use of information systems and technology has given the company not only a cutting edge advantage over other companies but also set examples how other companies can follow its footsteps. The paper describes several processes showing how Airbus business model is configured to a network infrastructure embellished with information system and technology. It continues how information flows across and up and down the company at various level and helps developing company-customer relationship ensuring quality products and services. Finally, a SWOT analysis is conducted showing room for further opportunities and prolific use of Information system and technology.} 
\keywords{Airbus, information systems, technology}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\section{Introduction}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The class is behaving exactly as it is supposed to. It's designed for submitting manuscripts to APA journals, and follows their requirements (no justification, running head on every page, etc.). You've chosen this by using the `man` option. If you choose the `jour` option you will see the difference. Are you submitting to an APA journal? If not, perhaps you don't really need the APA class at all. See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793).

Comment: P.S. Don't use the `utf8x` input encoding. See [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067)

Comment: Thanks Alan for the comments. Just wondering if there is any on the fly option to suppress/hide the "title" before Introduction on page 3.

Comment: No I'm not submitting APA journal. Just revisiting latex after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't recommend using the `apa6` class (at least with the `man` option) for purposes other than producing APA journal manuscripts, it's actually not too difficult to do what you need with the class.

To remove the extra title use the aptly named `[donotrepeattitle]` class option.

Since the `man` mode sets all the text to `\raggedright` and LaTeX has no built-in way to cancel that, it's easiest to load the `ragged2e` package which supplies a `justifying` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,12pt,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
\title{The Airbus}
\shorttitle{Airbus}
\author{Writer}
\affiliation{LSE}

\abstract{This paper provides an overview on the history of Airbus, its time evolution from early establishment to present day emphasizing on the information systems and technology. The objectives are to explore how Airbus as a manufacturing company embraced Information Systems and Technology to run its business and transformed into a data driven company. From its day-to-day operation to strategic plans, Airbus' use of information systems and technology has given the company not only a cutting edge advantage over other companies but also set examples how other companies can follow its footsteps. The paper describes several processes showing how Airbus business model is configured to a network infrastructure embellished with information system and technology. It continues how information flows across and up and down the company at various level and helps developing company-customer relationship ensuring quality products and services. Finally, a SWOT analysis is conducted showing room for further opportunities and prolific use of Information system and technology.} 
\keywords{Airbus, information systems, technology}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\section{Introduction}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

[image: abstract]
[image: first page]